# Cant get AlarmManager and broadcast working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

No matter how I try, I cannot get the alarmManager and receiver to work - there seem to be SO many different ways to do it from what i've searched, but nothing seems to work.

I have in Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver" />
```

I am using inner class for broadcastReceiver:

```
private class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("ALARM","TRIGGERED");
        Notification(filteredList.get(0).getTitle());
    }

}
```

I call function SetAlarm to start the manager:

```
private void SetAlarm(long time) {

    AlarmManager alarm_mgr = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    //PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 111, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    alarm_mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
    Log.d("ALARMSET", "Alarm " + calendar.getTime().toString());
}
```

As you can see, in the receiver I have a notification call - I won't post because I know this works, but there is also a log that is not working.
For testing purposes I've set time to current time using the Calendar function.
You can see the pendingIntent, i have tried both getService and getBroadcast, I can't figure out which I need, but neither works anyway.

I'm sure I'm missing something, i don't know what, and I can't seem to find any answers at Google.

Is the AlarmReceiver ok as an inner class ?  I have put it there because I need access to my "filteredList" List object.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, actually the `BroadcastReceiver` needs to be public.Only then you can register it in manifest and access them. Place the AlarmReceiver code in a separate .java file. You will see the log inside the `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: yep that works, now just need to find a way to access my list object, so that I can use a specific message in the notification.  Can i pass the receiver a string?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125009/android-passing-data-from-activity-to-broadcastreceiver-shows-null will help you towards passing data to broadcast receiver. if its working then u can accept my answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

> I am using inner class for broadcastReceiver:

This will not work. Android has to be able to create an instance of your `BroadcastReceiver`, and it cannot do so. At best, your `BroadcastReceiver` could be a *static* nested class, but then you would have to fix your manifest entry to refer to the outer class:

```
<receiver android:name="OuterClass$AlarmReceiver" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
```

...

```
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

// Set the alarm to start at 8:30 a.m.
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
 calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

 // setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
 // 20 minutes.
 alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
    1000 * 60 * 20, alarmIntent);
```

For more details.. Look [this](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

Answer (score 0):

I stucked 1 day for this problem, and finally solved this.

AlarmManager is used to generate a broadcast every 30 seconds, and a broadcast receiver is used to receive the message and execute ...

So the main problem is the following 2 steps

## 1. In the AndroidManifist.xml a action filter needed.

```
<receiver android:name="com.istep.gps.straight.MyTimerReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.istep.gps.straight.MyTimerReceiver.Action"/>
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

## 2. The most important is the Intent need to be empty, no AAA.class

```
 private void initTimer(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent().setAction("com.istep.gps.straight.MyTimerReceiver.Action")
                .putExtra("id",UniqueID.getID(context));

        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 18, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 1000 * 30, sender);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use calendar, you should `setTimeInMillis`

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
```